# what if the FD steps varied w.r.t output/input

Tags: openmdao

I am using the  finite difference scheme to find gradients. 
Lets say i have 2 outputs (y1,y2) and 1 input (x) in a single component. And in advance I know that the sensitivity of y1 with respect to x is not same as the sensitivity of y2 to x. And thus i could potentially have two different steps for those as in ;

```
self.declare_partials(of=y1, wrt=x, method='fd',step=0.01, form='central')
self.declare_partials(of=y2, wrt=x, method='fd',step=0.05, form='central')
```

There is nothing that stops me (algorithmically) but it is not clear what would openmdao gradient calculation exactly do in this case?

does it exchange information from the case where the steps are different by looking at the steps ratios or simply treating them independently and therefore doubling computational time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this, and it does the finite difference twice with the two different step sizes, and only saves the requested outputs for each step. I don't think we could do anything with the ratios as you suggested, as the reason for using different stepsizes to resolve individual outputs is because you don't trust the accuracy of the outputs at the smaller (or large) stepsize.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fair question about the effect of the API. In typical FD applications you would get only 1 function call per design variable for forward and backward difference and 2 function calls for central difference.

However in this case, you have asked for two different step sizes for two different outputs, both with central difference. So here, you'll end up with 4 function calls to compute all the derivatives. dy1_dx will be computed using the step size of .01 and dy2_dx will be computed with a step size of .05.

There is no crosstalk between the two different FD calls, and you do end up with more function calls than you would have if you just specified a single step size via:

```
self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt=x, method='fd',step=0.05, form='central')
```

If the cost is something you can bear, and you get improved accuracy, then you could use this method to get different step sizes for different outputs.